# How to use call main outlook window

Tags: autohotkey

My work has just upgraded our phone system to be able to make calls directly from Outlook.

If I don't have any open emails then this works (copy number to clipboard first):

```
#p::
RunOrActivate("outlook.exe")
send {alt}xcg
SendRaw %clipboard% 
Send {enter}
exit
```

The phone call feature is an Add-In in Outlook. Is there a way I can call the main outlook window and not an open email? Perferably a way that also doesn't open an extra instance of Outlook.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have a `RunorActivate` function.  Can you add that code as well? Also, are there any differences in the window titles of an email and the main Outlook window?

Comment: I am curious about where your phone numbers come from. If they aren't alreay in your (global) address book, wouldn't it be easier to just add them to your contacts? Provided, your add-in can use these contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Window Title instead of the exe name to select the Outlook Window. Using the Exe as you are will pick the Outlook window at the top of the Zorder. Use WinActivate with an unambiguous pattern that will select the main Outlook window.  Exact string depends on Which version of Outlook you have.